# PrimeFaces SelectOneRadio Custom Layout in two columns

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am using custom layout for SelectOneRadio component of PrimeFaces.

```
<h:outputLabel style="font-size: 22px" for="SignMethodRadio" value="Select your Signmethod : "/>
<p:selectOneRadio id="signMethodRadio" value="#{selectSignMethodView.signMethod}" layout="custom">
   <f:selectItems value="#{selectSignMethodView.signMethodList}" var="sm" itemLabel="#{sm}" itemValue="#{sm}"/>
   <f:ajax listener="#{selectSignMethodView.changeServers}" event="change" execute="@form" render="server"/>
</p:selectOneRadio>

<ui:repeat value="#{selectSignMethodView.signMethodList}" var="signMethod" varStatus="loop">
    <p:panel>
        <p:radioButton for=":signMethodForm:signMethodRadio" itemIndex="#{loop.index}"/>
        <h:outputText style="font-weight: bold" value=" #{signMethod} : "/>
        <h:outputText value="File Types allowed are : #{signMethod.fileTypes}"/>
    </p:panel>
</ui:repeat>
```

My custom layout consists of radio Button followed by two output text component. My problem is that they all appear in single column. I want this custom layout to appear in two columns i.e., my custom radio components appearing in two columns. My current layour looks like this :

[image: Single Column]

And I want it to be like this.

[image: Two Columns]

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the primefaces dataGrid in combination with h:panelGroup instead of ui:repeat

```
<p:dataGrid value="#{selectSignMethodView.signMethodList}" var="signMethod" columns="2" rowIndexVar="index">
  <h:panelGroup>
      <p:radioButton for=":signMethodForm:signMethodRadio" itemIndex="#{index}"/>
      <h:outputText style="font-weight: bold" value=" #{signMethod} : "/>
      <h:outputText value="File Types allowed are : #{signMethod.fileTypes}"/>
   </h:panelGroup>
</p:dataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as below :

```
<style>
    .selection tr {
       float: left;
        width: 50%;
    }
</style>

<h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="selection">
    <p:selectOneRadio layout="pageDirection"> 
        <!--Here is example data-->
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="A"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="B"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="C"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="D"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="E"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="F"/>
    </p:selectOneRadio>
</h:panelGroup>
```

`widht:50%` mean `100/2` calculation for two columns. For three columns will be `width:33%`.

In Primefaces 5.0, there is a `grid` layout with column.

```
<p:selectOneRadio layout="grid" columns="2">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="A"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="B"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="C"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="D"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="E"/>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="F"/>
</p:selectOneRadio>
```

Comment: keep your <f:selectItem s>  in <h:panelGrid columns="2"> </h:panelGrid>